# How can I view my custom 500 error page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I published Laravel's error pages and customized them. I can test a 404 error, for example, but if I throw an Exception in my controller to test the 500 error page, the debug page of Laravel is displayed instead of my custom 500 error page. How can I test the 500 error page my users will actually see?

Comment: Did you try turning debug mode off via `APP_DEBUG=false` in your `.env` file?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of throwing an Exception in your controller, just call `abort(500)`. This will display your custom 500 page.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `APP_DEBUG=false` in the .env  file and when the program encounters an error, it will display the 500 page.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. Also, please explain what you mean by "run an error"